# How do i switch between google scripts in my google doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

So we have a google doc with an associated script. I created a copy script to do edits on. How do i switch between these two scripts when working with the google doc?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this docs is a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), then you can only open it by selecting Tools in the doc itself then click the Script editor... to view the script.

Now, if you create this script not only for this docs, or by using script.google.com. then you can open/run it with these two ways.

- Select the Run menu, followed by the name of the function you want to execute.
- Choose the name of the function you want to execute from the select box in the toolbar, then click ▶.